# program to make a single function having search and sorting of an array

Tags: arrays, c, function, sorting, search

Write a program to sort the elements of 1D array in descending order and also implement linear search on
the same array. Both sorting and searching operations should be done inside one user defined function: “Task”.
So, for achieving the required functionality, pass array into the function: Task () from main () using Pass by
reference/ or address approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this code ,I use a boolean function ,this function orders the elements of array in descending order,then he check if the value exist in the value or no (return true if the value exist and false if the value don't exist)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool linear_search(int N,int A[N],int VAL);

int main()
{
    int VAL,POS,N;
    do
    {
        printf("Give me the length of array : ");
        scanf("%d", &N );
    }while(N<1);

    int A[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
         printf("Element number %d : ", i);
         scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    printf("Element of find : ");
    scanf("%d", &VAL );
    printf("\nDisplay the array \n");
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }

    if(linear_search(N,A,VAL)==true)
    {
        printf("\n\nThe value %d exist in this array \n",VAL);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("\n\nThe value does not exist in this array \n");
    }
    printf("\n");

   return 0;
}

bool linear_search(int N,int A[N],int VAL)
{
     for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
     {int temp=0;
         for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
         {
             if(A[j]>A[i])
             {
                  temp=A[i];
                  A[i]=A[j];
                  A[j]=temp;
             }
         }
     }
     int POS = -1;
     for(int i=0 ; (i<N)&&(POS==-1) ; i++)
     {
         if (A[i]==VAL)
         {
             POS=i;
         }
    }

    if (POS==-1)
    {
        return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```